# Durand-Kerner with derivative in denominator

Tags: algorithm, math, polynomial-math, polynomials

The correction term for Durand-Kerner root finding method is

```
$w_k = -\frac{f(z_k)}{\prod_{j\not=k}(z_k - z_j)}$
```

Wikipedia [Talk page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Durand%E2%80%93Kerner_method#Connection_to_Newton_method) mentions that it is also possible to use derivative in denominator, instead of the above product.

How to form such derivative? All I have are coefficients of the polynomial and the approximations of the roots. How to come up with coefficients for the derivative so I can evaluate it with Horner scheme like I do it for evaluation of polynomial (the $f(z_k)$)?

Am I correctly assuming that the derivative is looks perhaps like $g'(x)$ where $g(x) = \prod(z_k - z_j)$?

PS: I tried to implement the expression by Bo Jacoby from the Talk page but I cannot get it to work: I tried to sum all the products of all the approximations but one and put the result into denominator but it doesn't seem to work that way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the derivative in the denominator, you get Newtons method. You can get the derivative value via a coupled Horner scheme or you can form the derivative polynomial and just evaluate that. You would need to document how you evaluate the polynomial value.

A combination using the derivative resp. Newton step and the current root approximations is the Aberth-Ehrlich method.

---

The linked discussion is about the fact that the product in the denominator can be interpreted as a derivative of an auxiliary polynomial. The discussed formula

> (d/dx)((x-p)(x-q)(x-r)(x-s)) = (x-q)(x-r)(x-s)+(x-p)(x-r)(x-s)+(x-p)(x-q)(x-s)+(x-p)(x-q)(x-r)

remains true in higher degrees. Note that when evaluating at an approximate root, i.e., one of `p,q,r,s`, only one product term remains.

This can be used for fast evaluation in high degrees where fast interpolation/multi-point evaluation algorithms based on fast polynomial multiplication are faster than the naive implementations with complexity quadratic in the degree.

---

For moderate degrees it is faster to evaluate the products as given (n*(n-2) mults). Assembling the linear factors into the approximate polynomial and then evaluating the derivative polynomial at the approximations requires a higher effort (about n²/2 mults more).

---

To compute the polynomial `g(z)` in the "naive" way, you have to repeatedly multiply a polynomial with a linear factor

```
[ a[m], ..., a[0] ] * [ 1, -zz ] 
    = [ a[m], a[m-1] - zz*a[m],..., a[0] - zz*a[1], -zz*a[0] ]
```

This can be done in-place by starting from the top, i.e., the highest degree

```
a[m+1] = a[m]
for k=m downto 1
    a[k] = a[k-1]-zz*a[k]
end for
a[0] = -zz*a[0]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! Unfortunately I still don't get it, it's my fault as I'm not able to explain it very well because it is a bit new to me. Let me try again: I have the DK correction term, ok. Can I replace the denominator with an evaluation of the derivative of P? You and the Talk page seem to say yes but I'm not sure it is the same: DK root approximations kind of "repel" each other whereas Newton iteration could easily converge to the same root multiple times.

Comment: See the math.se answer. D-K is wk=-f(zk)/g'(zk) where g(z)=(z-z1)…(z-zn). Using wk=-f(zk)/f'(zk) is the univariate Newton method and, correct, the individual iterations are decoupled.

Comment: I see. But how to get the coefficients of `g'`? So I can evaluate it with Horner scheme? In other words, I have the coefficient of P (a0, a1, ...) and evaluate it with Horner like `value = value * guess + ai`. Ok. But how to compute the `g'(x)`? PS: Should I better post on math.se?

Comment: As I said, you don't. Just compute the product of root differences.

Comment: I see. But I would like to. Isn't it somehow possible? And now you might ask why would anyone want to do it that way. Well...I can try to explain... Would you prefer chat or math.se? Or here?

Comment: It's a programming question. Added section on repeated multiplication by a linear factor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87786/discussion-between-ecir-hana-and-lutzl).